# ImageResizer - Outputting resized images with embedded ICC profiles

Tags: imageresizer, color-profile, color-management

I've been playing around with ImageResizer for a week or so now and am wondering if it's possible to output resized images with the same ICC profile embedded (and in the same colour space) as the source image, for example the Adobe 1998 colour space?

I intend to use ImageResizer as part of my company's workflow for thumbnailling our source images before our imaging dept looks at them for consistency, so the same colour profile is essential. Generation speed isn't too important as they will be cached once generated.

Can someone please tell me if ImageResizer is capable of this and which parts of the pipeline I would need to overload to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ImageResizer targets the web, always produces images in the sRGB color space; browsers don't support ICC profiles, so we don't use them.

That said, you can certainly modify a few lines and get the result you want.

ImageResizer has 3 pipelines - GDI+ (the default), FreeImage, and WIC.

- GDI+ does not support output profiles - at least not through System.Drawing.
- FreeImage is supposed to have very good ICC profile support
- WIC should have ICC profile support as well, but is likely to share bugs with GDI+ as both use the same codecs.

To make changes, go to the [ImageResizer repository](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/tree/develop) and click the 'fork' button.

When you clone your fork, be *sure* that you switch to the develop branch before making changes - otherwise your changes will not be compatible with the next major version.

You'll probably want to modify [Plugins/FreeImage/FreeImageEncoder.cs](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/develop/Plugins/FreeImage/FreeImageEncoder.cs). FreeImage [documentation is in pdf form (yay!)](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/freeimage/FreeImage3160.pdf), so you'll probably want to scan that quickly to understand how it handles profiles.

When testing, make sure you enable the 3 FreeImage plugins by installing them *and* activating them via their command strings, `&builder=freeimage` will activate the full FreeImage pipeline, but `&encoder=freeimage` will just activate the encoder portion (useful if you want to edit the image with GDI+, but save via FreeImage).

You will likely also want to use the `ignoreIcc=true` command, so that you don't see sRGB values interpreted as Adobe RGB.